# Regular expression for a number criterion

Tags: regex

Can I get the regular expression for the following criteria?

Number format only

- *If* number starts with `07` *then* min length = 11 and max length = 11.
- *If* number starts with `01`, `02`, `03`, `04`, `05`, `06`, `08`, `09` *then* min length = 10 and max length = 11.

I tried this but doesnt seem to be working.

```
^[0]{1}([0-6,8-9]{10,11}|[7]{11})$
```

Comment: what would be the remaining characters after `07` or `01`,..?

Comment: post some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: `{1}` is a no-op. It means "the previous symbol/group exactly once". It has the same effect if you just omit it.

Comment: `[0]{1}` suggests a regex tutorial would be a good place to start.

Comment: you mean this `^(?:0[1-68-9]{10,11}|7{11})$`

Comment: @AvinashRaj After 07 or 01, all the remaining characters are numbers

Comment: please consider replying on very first.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this regex pattern:

`^(?:07\d{9}|0[1-689]\d{8,9})$`

or equivalent

`^(?:07[0-9]{9}|0[1-689][0-9]{8,9})$`

*Explanation*:
`07\d{9}` = `0`, `7`, and exactly 9 digits

`0[1-689]\d{8,9}` = `0`, `1`, `any digit but 7`, and 8 or 9 digits after.

In your regex, you specify `[7]{11}` = `7` digit repeated 11 times, `[0-6,8-9]{10,11}` meaning "any digit but 7 or a comma 10 or 11 times". All that prevents matching all digits where you need them. The length restriction should also take into account the number of already matched digits.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer (a tick mark under the down arrow on the left, next to my answer).